# How to create custom Authorization in ASP.NET Core (ASP.NET 5)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I would like to have custom implementation of [Authorize] attribute in controlles.

This is what I did.

1. StartupClass in ConfigureServices

   ```
   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
   {    
       options.AddPolicy("Authorize", policy =>
       {   
            policy.AddRequirements(new MyRequirement());
       });
   });
   ```
2. MyRequirement

   ```
   public class MyRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<MyRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
   {
       protected override void Handle(AuthorizationContext context, MyRequirement requirement)
       {
           //some work
           //if shloud be authorized
           context.Succeed(requirement);
       }
   }
   ```
3. TestController

   ```
   [Authorize("Authorize")]
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
   public class TestController : Controller
   {
     ...
   }
   ```

What I'm I missing? MyRequirement authorizationhader is never called.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you actually authenticated? Authorization won't kick into policies until you have an identity.

Comment: I'm not. Looks like I'm looking for Basic Authentication middleware..

Comment: Do you mean basic as in HTTP auth, or basic as in, I want to shove this identity on every request whilst I test?

Comment: I would like to add token to every request(into header) and validate it by custom logic.

Comment: If a JWT token will suffice there is middleware for that. If you want your own token, then you need to write your own middleware to create an identity before any policies ever get evaluated.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are missing this part:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MyRequirementHandler>();
```

[Source](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html#authorization-handlers)

Comment: Is possible to apply a Policy without a name so that the Policy will be applied in all authorize request ?

Comment: How to get access to headers from here?

Comment: @mr_squall if you need access to headers in order to get the user/claims principal you can use **context.user.Identity** by typecasting it as ClaimsIdentity