# Custom authorization in ASP.NET Core with enum roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization

I'm trying to add custom authorization to an ASP.NET Core 6 Razor Pages app using Policies. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31465227/177416) from one of the Microsoft people recommends implementing an `IAuthorizationRequirement`.

Here's the wrinkle: I need to use an `enum` for the roles that are listed in the `Authorize` attribute, such as `[Authorize(RoleEnum = Role.SysAdmin | Role.Manager)]`, similar to how we could do in Framework with the `[Flags]` attribute.

I've written the following requirement based on [Microsoft's own code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/62351067ff4c1401556725b401478e648b66acdc/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/RolesAuthorizationRequirement.cs) and I've changed it to use enums:

```
public class RolesAuthorizationRequirement: AuthorizationHandler<RolesAuthorizationRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public RolesAuthorizationRequirement(IEnumerable<Constants.Role> allowedRoles)
    {
        if (allowedRoles == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(allowedRoles));
        }

        if (allowedRoles.Count() == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No roles provided.");
        }
        AllowedRoles = allowedRoles;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Constants.Role> AllowedRoles { get; }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RolesAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User != null)
        {
            bool found = false;
            if (requirement.AllowedRoles == null || !requirement.AllowedRoles.Any())
            {
                // Review: What do we want to do here?  No roles requested is auto success?
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                found = requirement.AllowedRoles.Any(r => context.User.IsInRole(r.ToString()));
            }
            if (found)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I tried adding it to services but it complains that it needs the roles in the c'tor of `RolesAuthorizationRequirement`:

```
options.AddPolicy("Authorize", 
    policy => policy.AddRequirements(new RolesAuthorizationRequirement()));
```

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35895842/177416), I'll need this as well:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MyRequirementHandler>();
```

What am I missing? How do you wire this all up? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something much simpler. Create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` that converts the enum roles to comma separated string roles that the default authorization mechanism expects:

```cs
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(Constants.Role roleEnum)
    {
        Roles = roleEnum.ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    }   
}

// assuming you have a Role enum similar to this:

public static class Constants
{
    [Flags]
    public enum Role
    {
        User = 1,
        SuperUser = 2,
        Admin = 4,
        SuperAdmin = 8
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
// instead of:
[Authorize(Roles = "User,Admin")]
// you can do:
[CustomAuthorize(Constants.Role.User | Constants.Role.Admin)]
```

Comment: Thanks, @DimitrisMaragkos. This is the simplest solution and elegant too.